# mysql_query doesn't work correct

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I want to update my table and increase data in column "a1".

problem: for example `a1=a1+2` but it will be `a1=a1+4`.
a1 is INT

```
mysql_query("update table set a1=a1+1 where username='".$user."'");
```

but its will be:

```
mysql_query("update table set a1=a1+(2*number) where username='".$user."'");
```

Comment: Are you sure your query is not executed 2 times? What will happen when you replace it with `a1=a1+a1` if `a1` is 3 at the beginning? Will the result be 9 or 12?

Comment: a1=a1+a1 => 12.its executed just once

Comment: If the result is 12, it is executed twice :) You just have to figure why. (`a1` is 3, then on first execution it will be 3+3=6. On second execution of your query, it will be 6+6=12.)

Comment: i know but my query is not in loop and i write it just once.but i dont know why it executed twice

Comment: Can you show us more of that code? Isn't the page being loaded in browser 2 times? Can you confirm that from the webserver logs?

Comment: <?php
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("DB CON ERR");
    $sel=mysql_select_db("testdb") or die("DB SEL ERR");

    $user="test";
    mysql_query("update users set a1=a1+1 where username='".$user."'");
?>